# Reading RGB value from a pixel in Java

Tags: java, image, colors, rgb, pixel

I´m trying to read the RGB values from a pixel that is drawn but I only get one value. When I try to get values for alpha, red, green and blue it always says "0" for every one except for blue where I actually get a value, and this value is always the same as "rgb". My code is shown here below and I would appreciate it if anyone of you can think of a solution.

```
int rgb = image.getRGB(250, 10);
rgb = rgb/-65793;
System.out.println(rgb);
Color färg = new Color(rgb, true);
int r = färg.getRed();
int g = färg.getGreen();
int b = färg.getBlue();
int a = färg.getAlpha();
System.out.println(r);
System.out.println(g);
System.out.println(b);
System.out.println(a);
```

What is printed is the following:

```
38
0
0
38
0
```

Comment: Why are you dividing by `-65793`?

Comment: I understand that “färg” means color in Swedish. Unfortunately ä is a non-ASCII character which later may give you nasty encoding problems when sharing code with others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
BufferedImage bi = ...;
int x = ..;
int y = ..;
Color converted = new Color(bi.getRGB(x, y));
```

You don't have to divide RGB value.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need for dividing the binary value.

Try this:

```
int rgb = img.getRGB(250, 10);
Color color = new Color(rgb);

// get colors (e.g. red)
int red = color.getRed();
System.out.println(red);

// retrieve alpha value via bitshifting
int alpha = (rgb & 0xff000000) >>> 24
System.out.println(alpha);
```